# Custom permalink with two parameters

Tags: permalinks

I am using custom structure for permalink: `/%postname%/%page%/%year%/`.

When I navigate to `http://wordpress-serv/projects-teams/designers/19/2013`, it gives me 404 "Page not found".

Nonetheless, it is working fine with `http://wordpress-serv/projects-teams/designers/19` (without year) and `get_query_var('page');` is returning `19`. Now, I just need the value of `get_query_var('year')` instead of getting weird 404..

Here is what the .htaccess file looks like:

```
AddHandler php-stable .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Is there any limit for number of parameters that can be set in custom permalinks? Any suggestions, what might be going wrong?

Comment: there's no limit, but each rule has to be a unique pattern, or the one with higher priority will "win". I'll guess your rule is clashing with WordPress's own rules for the `page` post type. try the [rewrite analyzer plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) to see how your rules are being parsed. If this is the case, the answer is unfortunately that you must change your structure, or remove the offending rules and lose the ability to use the `page` post type.

Comment: @Milo, `page` is working perfectly fine. The problem is with `year`..

Comment: as Jerry mentions, %page% isn't a valid rewrite tag for posts. If you try the plugin I linked above I think you'll see that it's trying to load the `page` post type.

Comment: @Milo, I am using pages. But that's not the point `page` is working fine and I'm using `get_query_var('page');` for custom pagination. I need `get_query_var('year');` for further filtration on top of pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, I had to finally gave up on pretty link and changed the permalink back to:

> /%postname%/%page%

Then I changed the URLs to `http://wordpress-serv/projects-teams/designers/19?fyear=2013` in shortcode, I passed $_GET['fyear'] and with the ugly query string it just works.

Answer (score 0):

According to the WP codex it doesn't look like there is a %page% tag. See the codex for a list of structure tags. The codex states

> You must use one of the structure tags, or a combination of tags only.

That might be the issue.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks

OR

Since the codex states

> Make sure to end your structure with either %post_id% or %postname% (e.g. /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/) so that each permalink points to an individual post.

You could try ending the permalink with the %page% tag to see if that works.

ex. /%postname%/%year%/%page%/ (It might or might not work but worth a shot)

Comment: `/%postname%/%year%/%page%/` is producing the same result: 404 Page not found..

Comment: It was worth a shot. There is no %page% tag that WP makes available.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do this using the permalink structure field. As Jerry pointed out, you can't use the `%page%` rewrite tag in the structure. WordPress uses this tag when rewrite rules are generated to automatically handle pagination. This is how you can set a normal permalink structure and pagination just works- it's handled internally for you.

You'll have to add your own rewrite rule to make it work, something like:

```
function wpa_rewrite_rule(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]&year=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_rewrite_rule' );
```

You'll probably also need to filter the [`post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_link) to generate the correct URLs in this format for any API calls to output single post URL.

Comment: and goodbye to month and daily archives :)

Comment: Ok, forget about `%page%` and custom code for overriding rewrite rules. According to documentation, `/%postname%/%post_id%/%page%/` is valid custom permalink. But even with this, the URL `http://wordpress-serv/projects-teams/designers/19/41` returns 404.

Comment: where in documentation does it say that's a valid permalink structure? have you tried the plugin I linked in my very first comment? it will show you exactly why your requests 404.

Comment: @Milo, in documentation these are the "valid tags". The permalink structure doesn't capture and map the URL parts to the tags, after the second tag in the sequence. I am using the plugin but its of no value as I can't remedy the problem..

Comment: regarding valid structure tags, [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks) says otherwise. the plugin doesn't help fix things, but it illustrates why it's not possible with the permalink structure field. I feel like I'm repeating myself here...